# Clang on Raspberry Pi/Raspbian Error?

Tags: linux, linker, debian, clang, raspberry-pi

When I try to run clang as my C compiler I get an error (I think a linker error)

```
Compilation started at Sun Nov 11 14:34:55

make -k 
clang -std=c99 -ggdb  -o0 -Wall -Werror helloworld.c -o helloworld
clang: warning: unknown platform, assuming -mfloat-abi=soft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [helloworld] Error 1

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Sun Nov 11 14:34:56
```

I actually re-installed the Raspbian image thinking that the problem would go away but it persists. Raspbian version is the latest Raspbian Wheezy hard float ABI (2012-10-28).

Answer (score 4):

As you've essentially figured out, the installed clang is unusably broken.  If you installed this through a package manager, complain to whoever distributes the package, because they clearly didn't bother testing it.